# Msi Setup Project Kill Process Before Installing

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-project

I did msi setup project in visual studio.Available 'blabla.exe' running in my computer.How to kill available process before msi setup installing.I maked that,custom actions add vbsript,.exe process or one of them condition but didn't run those way.How to make it?

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you explained if you're having an issue with the default behavior. Are you seeing a FilesInUse dialog that you want to suppress? Does the running exe cause the install to fail?  I don't understand the term "available process" either.  So if there's an actual problem, please explain what it is.

Custom actions in a setup project won't solve the problem (whatever it is) because custom actions in a Visual Studio setup project all run after the product has been installed, so there's nothing they can do earlier in the install.